# Exchange Move Mailbox status : StalledDueToTarget_ContentIndexing

Tags: exchange-2010, migration, exchange-2016

We are migrating from MS Exchange 2010 SP3 to 2016 (CU7). 
All servers are on premises.

We moved several mailboxes from a 2010 server to 2016 without issue.

Now for 3 mailboxes the MoveRequest stall. The status showed by a "Get-MoveRequestStatistics" is :

> Status  : Queued
>   StatusDetail  : StalledDueToTarget_ContentIndexing

What we have tried:

- stop or restart the services `Microsoft Exchange Search` and `Microsoft Exchange Search host controller`
- checked that the group `ContentSubmitters` exist (it did) and add Full Controll for "Network services", then restart the search services.
- Disabled content indexing on the target database with the command `Set-MailboxDatabase "dbID" -IndexEnabled $false`
- Removing and recreating the move request after those
- Suspending and resuming the move request
- Moving the mailbox to 3 other exchange 2010 databases then trying to move them to a 2016 server, to various destination databases

Still no luck.

How can I have those move requests to succeed?

Comment: Does these 3 mailbox are in a separated db? or they were all in the same db before the move ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Forget to add, I also moved the mailbox to 3 different 2010 database, to start from a clean status, editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the indexing to false, then when time appropriate set true.  The mailbox indexing should always be true, but when migrating mailboxes may become challenging.  Use this on a limited basis as indexing should always default to true!

```
Set-MailboxDatabase "your mailbox database" -IndexEnabled:$False
Set-MailboxDatabase "your mailbox database" -IndexEnabled:$True
```

Comment: Thanks, but we already tried that, see 3rd bullet point in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it occur on one special target database in Exchange 2016?
If so, try to disable the content indexing on this database and re-move again.

> Set-MailboxDatabase “your mailbox database” -IndexEnabled:$False

Also, stop Exchange search service and **remove search index file** (\V15\Mailbox\).